# Azure DevOps error when trying to execute a task using an array

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an AZD deploy template as below. I am trying to execute a task (Kubernetes@1) multiple times looping an array that is defined in parameters.

```
  parameters:
  - name: env
  - name: serviceConnection
  - name: 'serviceNames'
    type: object
    default:
    - audit
    - export
    - admin

jobs:

  - deployment: Deployment
    displayName: Deploy to ${{ parameters.env }}
    environment: ${{ parameters.env }}
    pool: on-prem-pool
    variables:
      - template: azure-deploy-vars.yaml
        parameters:
          env: ${{ parameters.env }}
    timeoutInMinutes: 10
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - script: |
                echo "Prepare to deploy config for ${{ parameters.serviceNames}}. clean workspace"
                ls -la
                cd ..
                ls -la
                rm -rf config
                rm -rf devops
                rm -rf TestResults
                rm -rf helm
                rm -f config.sh
                rm -f *.properties
              displayName: 'Clean Workspace'

            - checkout: config
              path: config

          - ${{ each service in parameters.serviceNames }}:
            - task: Kubernetes@1
              displayName: Deploy Config
              inputs:
                connectionType: Kubernetes Service Connection
                kubernetesServiceEndpoint: '${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}'
                namespace: '$(PROJECT_NAMESPACE)'
                configMapName: '${{ service }}'
                forceUpdateConfigMap: true
                useConfigMapFile: true
                configMapFile: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/config/${{ service }}/${{ parameters.env }}/application-${{ parameters.env }}.properties'
```

But I get this error when I try to run the pipeline.
Can anyone see point me if there is an error in my template?

Error:

```
/ci/azure-deploy.tpl.yaml: (Line: 41, Col: 11, Idx: 1048) - (Line: 41, Col: 12, Idx: 1049): While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indent the line

```
- ${{ each service in parameters.serviceNames }}:
```

so that it matches the `- script:` and `- checkout:` lines above it, and then increases the indent of the following lines as well.

Corrected template:

```
parameters:
  - name: env
  - name: serviceConnection
  - name: 'serviceNames'
    type: object
    default:
    - audit
    - export
    - admin

jobs:

  - deployment: Deployment
    displayName: Deploy to ${{ parameters.env }}
    environment: ${{ parameters.env }}
    pool: on-prem-pool
    variables:
      - template: azure-deploy-vars.yaml
        parameters:
          env: ${{ parameters.env }}
    timeoutInMinutes: 10
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - script: |
                echo "Prepare to deploy config for ${{ parameters.serviceNames}}. clean workspace"
                ls -la
                cd ..
                ls -la
                rm -rf config
                rm -rf devops
                rm -rf TestResults
                rm -rf helm
                rm -f config.sh
                rm -f *.properties
              displayName: 'Clean Workspace'

            - checkout: config
              path: config

            - ${{ each service in parameters.serviceNames }}:
            - task: Kubernetes@1
              displayName: Deploy Config
              inputs:
                connectionType: Kubernetes Service Connection
                kubernetesServiceEndpoint: '${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}'
                namespace: '$(PROJECT_NAMESPACE)'
                configMapName: '${{ service }}'
                forceUpdateConfigMap: true
                useConfigMapFile: true
                configMapFile: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/config/${{ service }}/${{ parameters.env }}/application-${{ parameters.env }}.properties'
```